# Python: Access help or man page for the methods of list and dictionaries on the idle command line. For exams we can only use idle

Tags: python, list, dictionary, methods

Is there a way with python to get the help or man page of all the methods for dictionaries or list on the command line or idle? So if your on an exam and can't google stuff you can still look them up? My allergies are terrible and I'm worried I'll confuse those methods that are for list, dictionaries or sets. I asked my instructor and google but she didn't think so, but she didn't know how to access the help page for modules so she may not fully be an expert. Like with modules you can on the command line just do for example: import(math); help(math) then it list all the functions in a module.

Comment: Did you try typing `help(list)`? I wonder about your instructor if they didn't know about that.

Comment: IDLE has a command prompt, where you can do all Python API calls. In the text editor, you obviously cannot do this, but you can just launch the interactive interpreter built into IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

IDLE supports the full built-in [`help()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) out of the box. In the interactive interpreter, just use `help(object)` to print out the documentation for that object.

You can use this on modules, classes, and methods:

[image: help on math in IDLE]